# How to delete file from "stage area"?

Tags: git

After I made a commit, I want to clean the stage area. Here is what I did:

```
git add 1.txt    ----- stage the 1.txt file
git commit -m "commit 1.txt"  ----- commit the 1.txt file
git reset HEAD 1.txt   ----- I want to clean the stage area
```

Then I check the stage area with this command:

```
git ls-files
```

The 1.txt is still shown.

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer:

Your staging is clean, atleast wrt HEAD if not the working directory too, once you commit.

Long answer:

You have committed the file `1.txt`. When you commit the index (staging) and HEAD become the same. And when you do `git reset HEAD 1.txt`, it is basically a noop, as both index and HEAD have the same version of 1.txt.

And `git ls-files` will display `1.txt` because the file is in your repo.

Not really sure what you are trying to do. But once you have committed a file, you can unstage the modifications you have done to it. In the case of a newly added file, unstaging the modifications is the same as removing the newly added file from index and hence unstaging it. But that is not the same for a file already in the repo.

Ideal way to remove file from staging, is `git rm --cached` - and when you commit, you remove the file from the repo as well. Remember that staging is the view of what HEAD will be once you commit.

But I think `git rm --cached` is not what you want to do as you just want a clean staging / index. After you commit it is clean anyway ( atleast wrt HEAD if not the working directory).

Answer (score 5):

Commiting changes will clean the stage area, you don't have to do anything after commit.

Otherwise use `git reset`:

```
git add 1.txt    ----- stage the 1.txt file
git reset 1.txt    ----- remove 1.txt file from stage
```

Also, use `git status` instead of `git ls-files`.

Answer (score 0):

`git ls-files`  shows what you are currently tracking.  Whether you have committed that file or not.

If you have committed the file, it points to the same file that the actual commit points to.  If you do a `git diff --cached`, those will be the changes that your staging area has, but haven't been commited

The "staging area" is just the difference between what HEAD is pointing to in the repository and what the index is pointing to.  It's not a physical file that you flush.

Comment: the *git help ls-files* shows that "This command show information about files in the index and the working tree "

Comment: And 1.txt is in the working tree. git reset HEAD does nothing.

Comment: I think you have the concept of a "staging area" and what the index file is confused.  As far as 1.txt... you committed 1.txt, now it is in your working dir, your index and the repository.  What do you expect to happen to it after a reset?

Comment: I gave the same asnwer, with a bit more explanation. And staging area is same as index I think. That is how it is being used.

Answer (score -2):

The staging area confuses many [been there, got scars].

One of the better explanations is in the git wiki FAQ on why `git rm` is not the opposite of `git add` [here](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Why_is_.22git_rm.22_not_the_inverse_of_.22git_add.22.3F).

I use the visualisation of a storyboard wall where copies are posted (staged), and need to be actively removed from the wall as a separate action from any adjustments at you desk (working directory).

The staging area is also used during merging, to avoid cluttering your personal work area.

Answer (score -3):

Because git ls-files lists all the files tracked by git.

You probably want git status here.